# Date cant save into database

Tags: grails

I am new in groovy on grails.I am facing problem saving date from excelsheet into database.  My date is of form  `2014-02-15` . I made changes into config.groovy for date

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['dd/mm/yyyy','yyyy-MM-dd']
```

But still it will show me error message like

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'org.grails.importexcel.SandyData' on field 'purchaseOrderDate': rejected value [2014-02-15]; codes [org.grails.importexcel.SandyData.purchaseOrderDate.typeMismatch.error,org.grails.importexcel.SandyData.purchaseOrderDate.typeMismatch,sandyData.purchaseOrderDate.typeMismatch.error,sandyData.purchaseOrderDate.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.org.grails.importexcel.SandyData.purchaseOrderDate,typeMismatch.purchaseOrderDate,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [purchaseOrderDate]; default message [Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.String(org.joda.time.LocalDate)]
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
```

Can anybody give me solutions for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I see you're trying to use JodaTime. Install [Joda-Time plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) which provides integration with Joda and [basic data bindings](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/guide/dataBinding.html).